# How to hide empty columns and keep the remaining columns together in crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows

I want to hide the empty columns and fill the gap with next field in crystal report.
ex:
i have 
col1 col2 col3
val1 val2 val3

i used the suppress option with formula --

```
if isnull({val2}) true else false
```

if val2 is empty then its displaying the report as

```
col1      col3
val1      val3
```

instead i need to display it as

```
col1 col3
val1 val3
```

Thank you

Comment: this `if isnull({val2}) true else false` is the same as `isnull({val2})`

Comment: You cannot directly. Even if you create dynamic formulas instead of data fields, how should your report behave, if in one row you have only col1 present, in second row only col2 etc?

Comment: you could use a crosstab

Comment: try this. On the Custom Style screen -> Number Tab check the "Suppress If Zero" box.